# How do I preserve papalo?

Tags: food-preservation, herbs

I have a lot of papalo in my garden, and want to preserve it. What method should I choose to do this? I want to use it throughout the winter, and maybe some next year. The internet suggests that drying is not a great option, so I am looking for other preservation methods.

Comment: related : https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/18157/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/q/139/67 ; https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/44795/67

Comment: and that's why it's a comment, not an answer.  "related" is not just for you, it's for other people who come along, as there might be answers in here that are useful to people with similar questions.  And not all of the things that I linked to are about drying.  But I'd also recommend that you be careful with being rude, as we're all just volunteering our time here, and I'd rather spend time helping people that aren't going to be ungrateful

Comment: I upvoted both the question and answer as I view them both as contributions to the site. However, I find @Joe's comment relevant as he stated - *related*. I find the responses to his comment rude and feel the need to say that we have a 'Be Nice' policy. Please adhere to it.

Comment: I'm going to clean up these comments in a while, but first I want to emphasize the unacceptability of the underlying rudeness. Snark is not acceptable on Stack Exchange. Period. Also, flagging innocuous comments as rude/abusive is highly frowned upon.

Comment: A pointer for flagging comments: Comments should not solve the problem, by definition. Therefore, flagging a comment because it doesn't contain answers is nonsensical.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

It seems that you've already done some research on the subject, as you mention that it doesn't dry well.  Searching for 'papalo' using an internet search engine found http://www.appalachianfeet.com/2010/05/07/how-to-grow-and-use-papalo-wrecipes/ :

> It doesn’t dry well, but it can be frozen if it is pureed with water or oil and put into ice cube trays.

This method is mentioned in [one of the answers to a related question](https://cooking.stackexchange.com/a/15654/67).